# Background color also pinning with scroll magic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollmagic

I have a one page scrolling website that I'm working on. I am trying to use Scroll magic to pin the first section, and then have the remaining part of the website scroll over top of it. As you can see in my fiddle the first section is pinned, but the remaining sections only the content scrolls and not the background colors. I'm not sure why this is. You can see what I mean here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fxf4b2cg/)`...`

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Testing your fiddle in Chrome, I see the lighter gray background moving with the <p>Lorem ipsum...</p> and the dark gray background moving with the "Contact" text. Also, it's recommended to post code directly into your question, not just in an external link.

Comment: The color moves but it doesn't flow over the image at the top like the content of the section tags do. Why? I also created that fiddle as I know there would be no way for me to recreate what I was talking about with just code posted here.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fully understand what effect you are trying to achieve but if I understand you correctly it seems it would be easier to do this by setting the 'home' background-attachment to fixed in the CSS.

Comment: I guess my questions is why is the background sitting over top of the background colors in the section below. But the content is slide over top of the image?

Answer (score 0):

ScrollMagic sets position: fixed on elements that are "pinned". Fixed elements will [stack above their relative/static siblings](http://jsfiddle.net/rvh0vhms/).

Observe this simple HTML/CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

</style>

<div class="fixed"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sagittis suscipit enim, non sodales tortor ultrices ut. Duis ac sodales eros. In sed feugiat est, vulputate scelerisque orci. Ut eleifend accumsan nibh quis placerat. Etiam non auctor velit. Suspendisse potenti. In ullamcorper arcu vel elementum congue. Suspendisse a tellus sodales, tempor arcu in, egestas odio. Phasellus rutrum sed lorem eget scelerisque. Quisque sed metus a mauris tempor tristique ac eget est.</p>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rvh0vhms/

You should probably not use setPin() on your background image container, and instead just set the background image on a parent container or the body.